# can I use flutter_bloc to manages state in flutter packages?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm traying to create a packages to use it in a flutter application, the packages has some pages where I need to manage state, I want to use flutter_bloc but I don't know if that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just add flutter_bloc in your package pubspec.yml and use it.

Comment: I did it but when I try to run the application get error [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349603/flutter-can-i-implemment-blocprovider-in-the-app-tree-instead-of-implemmented-i)